# Camunda:InvalidRequestException: Process engine with name camundaProcessEngine does not exist

Tags: camunda

I have created Maven Camunda Java Project and inside `ServletProcessApplication` extended class namely, `MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine` I created one method `createProcessEngine()` to register `processEngine` through java API with `MSSQL Database`.
I'm following the community asked a question link https://forum.camunda.org/t/multi-tenancy-programmatically-create-tenant/2876

My

```
DbName:camunda2db,
dbusername:camunda2
dbpassword:camunda2
```

Except for the following code not at all, I did any configuration:

```
package com.camundatest;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.camunda.bpm.application.ProcessApplication;
    import org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.ServletProcessApplication;
    import org.camunda.bpm.container.RuntimeContainerDelegate;
    import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngine;
    import org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineConfiguration;

    @ProcessApplication
    public class MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine extends ServletProcessApplication{

          private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine.class);
          private void createProcessEngine(){
              LOGGER.info("\n\n**********Creating ProcessEngine *********");
              ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
                      .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE)
                      .setJdbcDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                      .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=camunda2db")
                      .setJdbcUsername("camunda2")
                      .setJdbcPassword("camunda2")
                      .setJobExecutorActivate(true)
                      .setProcessEngineName("camundaProcessEngine")
                      .setHistory(ProcessEngineConfiguration.HISTORY_FULL)
                      .buildProcessEngine();

              RuntimeContainerDelegate runtimeContainerDelegate = RuntimeContainerDelegate.INSTANCE.get();

              runtimeContainerDelegate.registerProcessEngine(processEngine);
              LOGGER.info("\n\n Process Engine: "+processEngine);
          }

          public static void main(String[] args) {
              MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine appProcessEngine = new MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine();
              appProcessEngine.createProcessEngine();
        }
    }
```

It's working fine in Java Application, but when I log in to camunda
with the URL:http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/admin/camundaProcessEngine/#/login

**throwing Exception: InvalidRequestException: Process engine with name camundaProcessEngine does not exist**

```
24-Mar-2018 17:39:33.463 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.RestExceptionHandler.toResponse org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.exception.InvalidRequestException: Process engine with name camundaProcessEngine does not exist
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.UserAuthenticationResource.doLogin(UserAuthenticationResource.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.EmptyBodyFilter.doFilter(EmptyBodyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilterSecure(SecurityFilter.java:67)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:58)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.SecurityActions.runWithAuthentications(SecurityActions.java:40)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know where I committing a mistake.Please help, any configuration need and link related to Programmatically create and register ProcessEngine in camunda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `MultiTenantProcessApplicationEngine` contains a main method, which is called if executed via `java` directly, but if you deploy this class annotated with `@ProcessApplication` the main method is never called. 
It simply deploys and register your application class.

If you use tomcat, jboss, wildfly or other application server a shared engine should be used. You can read about the different engine bootstrapping [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/process-engine/process-engine-bootstrapping/).

With your approach you will create an embedded engine.

If you want to read about the different runtime container integrations read this [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/runtime-container-integration/).

To configure/create a shared engine in jboss/wildfly for example, you have to add a subsystem to the `standalone.xml`.

This could look like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:org.camunda.bpm.jboss:1.1">
    <process-engines>
        <process-engine name="engineName" default="true">
            <datasource>java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine</datasource>
            <history-level>full</history-level>
            <properties>
                <property name="jobExecutorAcquisitionName">default</property>
                <property name="isAutoSchemaUpdate">true</property>
                <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
            </properties>
        </process-engine>
    </process-engines>
    <job-executor>
        <core-threads>3</core-threads>
        <max-threads>5</max-threads>
        <queue-length>10</queue-length>
        <job-acquisitions>
            <job-acquisition name="default">
                <properties>
                    <property name="lockTimeInMillis">300000</property>
                    <property name="waitTimeInMillis">5000</property>
                    <property name="maxJobsPerAcquisition">3</property>
                </properties>
            </job-acquisition>
        </job-acquisitions>
    </job-executor>
</subsystem>
```

You can read more about the configuration steps [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/runtime-container-integration/jboss/#configure-a-process-engine-in-standalone-xml-domain-xml).